# How to open framed version of Javadoc once Google lead you to non-framed?

Tags: javadoc, frames, fastutil

How to open framed version of Javadoc once Google lead you to non-framed?

For example: https://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/help-doc.html

How to switch to framed version?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot switch to a framed version, because there is no framed version. (The documentation you linked to was created with Javadoc 15.)

Up to version 10, Javadoc created HTML frames by default.

For versions 11 and 12, Javadoc did not create HTML frames unless option `--frames` was specified.

As of version 13, Javadoc is no longer able to create HTML frames.